# facebook graph api deserialization for page search

Tags: c#, json, facebook-graph-api, json-deserialization

I'm using Facebook graph API to search pages, https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=platform&type=page

Here is the response in json, i've included only one:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Media/news/publishing",
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "108366235907857",
          "name": "Newspaper"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Arab News",
      "id": "10250877124"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?limit=1&offset=1&type=page&q=media&__after_id=10250877124"
  }
}
```

Now, here are my classes in C#:

```
public class CategoryList
        {

            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class DataRoot
        {

            [JsonProperty("category")]
            public string Category { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("category_list")]
            public CategoryList[] CategoryList { get; set; }
        }

        public class Paging
        {

            [JsonProperty("next")]
            public string Next { get; set; }
        }

        public class FacebookPageResults
        {

            [JsonProperty("data")]
            public DataRoot[] Data { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("paging")]
            public Paging Paging { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is the odd thing, when i try to deserialize it 
`FacebookPageResults response = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FacebookPageResults>(res);` , the CategoryList is always null, doesn't even fill up. I have tried with List CategoryList {get; set;} but the result is the same?

Any help or workaround about thi

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering, i found the solution:

FacebookPageResults response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);

This works

Answer (score 0):

FacebookPageResults response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res.ToString());